# How to run latest Ubuntu touch development release on bq phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is it possible to run the Ubuntu Touch development release on the bq phone? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: Galgales: You're losing it!  You're showing up in the low quality review queue!  **;-)**  (Voted "Looks OK")

Comment: @Fabby, got a few downvotes too.. It would be useful if those people commented on why this is a bad question?

Comment: I'm one who always comments when voting unless smth is *obviously* bad. (which this isn't, so upvoted to counteract downvote) **;-)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the image channel:

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/image-channels/

But be careful, it is not recommended for daily use.